# GUI for cloning GIT repository

Tags: git, ubuntu-14.04, libreoffice

Is there any GIT GUI client available that resumes the cloning from where it stopped last time. I need to clone a repository into my machine that takes a disk space of 4 GB. However most of the time my connection resets most of the time mainly due to power failure, low battery.
OS - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
RAM - 6 GB

Comment: Plug your computer in?

Comment: What about power failure?

Comment: Get a UPS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

You cant continues from the point where you stopped.

Few notes:

***4GB repo???*** - something bad is going in in your repository.
Try to pack it in small zip/tar packages and then transfer them to your computer.
You have download managers or any other program that can resume.

Comment: no nothing is bad in the repo. it has Libreoffice source code and it is already zipped and its original size is about 30 gb.

Comment: If you mean this: http://dev-www.libreoffice.org/bundles/libreoffice-core.tar.bz2 - it is only 2gb and can be fetched with any client (wget for example)

Comment: git://anongit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core
this is the repo